# Flutter: accessing data in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

I have the following Firebase realtime database connected to my flutter project:

[image]

I am fairly new to flutter and firebase, I understand that a way to access the data in this database in my flutter project is by using a database reference variable. So i have the following reference variable `itemRef`:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  DatabaseReference itemRef;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    itemRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  }
```

Now, how do i access the temperature and pulse values in the database using this itemRef?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
itemRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
itemRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
  print(snapshot.value);
  var pulse = snapshot.value["pulse"];
  var temp  = snapshot.value["temperature"];
});
```

use the `once()` method to retrieve the data, then `snapshot.value` will be of type `Map<String,dynamic>` and you can access the attributes using the `get` operator.