# How to get another users ID from Firebase in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

[image]i'm trying to add user in my contacts by writing his uid from firebase. I need to write users id in textfield and on pressing button i need to firebase check this uid, and if it's exists, my app needs to add it in contacts. Is there any solutions? p.s i'm making messenger app and it's "Add new contact" function. It would be nice if someone tells me how to create chat using their ID or create separate "chat id" which would be same to 2 users. btw i'm using realtime database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if the user exsits, you can do something like this:

```dart
    final users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    final userDoc =
        await users.doc('PUT THE UID TO SEARCH FOR HERE').get();
    if (userDoc.exists) {
     // do something
    }
```

To make this reusable convert it to a function:

```dart
Future<bool> userExists(String uid) async {
    final users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    final userDoc =
        await users.doc(uid).get();
    return userDoc.exists;
}
```

Now you can call the function with any uid:

```
bool _userExists = await userExists('UID');
```

Here is a full code example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => new _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  // This key is used to control the SnackBars
  final key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();
  final textCtrlr = TextEditingController();
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    textCtrlr.dispose();
  }

  Future<bool> userExists(String uid) async {
    final users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    final userDoc = await users.doc(uid).get();
    return userDoc.exists;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ScaffoldMessenger(
        key: key, // Assign the key to the ScaffoldMessenger
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: textCtrlr,
                    ),
                    width: 200.0,
                  ),
                ),
                isLoading
                    ? const SizedBox(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          strokeWidth: 2.0,
                        ),
                        width: 20.0,
                        height: 20.0,
                      )
                    : ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          final uid = textCtrlr.text;

                          setState(() => isLoading = false);
                          final bool _userExists = await userExists(uid);
                          setState(() => isLoading = false);

                          if (_userExists) {
                            // The user exists and can
                            // be added to contacts
                            key.currentState?.showSnackBar(
                              SnackBar(
                                content: Text(
                                  'User added!',
                                ),
                                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                                behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                              ),
                            );
                            return;
                          }

                          // The user doesn't exist
                          key.currentState?.showSnackBar(
                            SnackBar(
                              content: Text(
                                'The user doesn\'t exist',
                              ),
                              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
                              behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: const Text('Search for user'),
                      ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it worked, but it's hardcoded, how i can make this variable(editable)?

Comment: I edited the answer, if it helped you mark it as correct. :)

Comment: i'm sorry if it's obvious, but i can't get it. where i should put "bool _userExists = await userExists('UID');" because when i tried to put it anywhere, it sayed that without async it can't work, but idk where in this case i must put async

Comment: You can add it to the function that happens when your Add button is pressed. For example when it is pressed you see if the user exists, if yes you add the user if not you show error message.

Comment: I currently have some work to do, but if you want I could give you a complete code example in maybe an hour?

Comment: it would be nice

Comment: I updated the answer, if it helped you please click on the green checkmark to mark the answer as correct :)

Comment: hello again, i know that i already marked that the question is closed, but can u tell me how i can made this "    final users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    final userDoc = await users.doc(uid).get();" part with Realtime Database?

Comment: I've never really used the the Realtime Database, so I can only suggest you to look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61496943/flutter-accessing-data-in-firebase-realtime-database?r=SearchResults